# Prove linear independence of functions $1,x,x^2,...,x^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

I need to prove that the set of functions  $\{1,x,x^2,\dots ,x^n\}$  is linearly independent in the space of continuous functions $С[0,1]$ for any value of $n\in\Bbb N$.

I know that I can do this using mathematical induction, but is there a simpler way? If there is can you please show one, thanks in advance.

Comment: Over the real numbers, I presume?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: hint: if a real polynomial is zero everywhere, then it is the zero polynomial.

Comment: Set up the equation for linear dependance/independance, put $x=0$ and conclude about the constant multiplying $1$. Derive the equation and then put $x=0$ and conclude ... and so on and so forth ...

Comment: Any linear combination  of these functions is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$. If this is not identically 0, ist has at most $n$ zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$ C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2+...+C_nx^n=0$$
Let $x=0$, to get $C_0=0$

Differentiate and let $x=0$ to get $$C_1=0$$

Differentiate again  and let $x=0$ to get $$C_2=0$$

and so forth until you come up with $$ C_0=C_1= C_2=...=C_n=0$$

Thus your set is linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $n$ distinct reals $x_k$ in $(0,1)$ and form the system of equations

$$C_0+C_1x_k+C_2x_k^2+\cdots C_nx_k^n=0$$ for $k=0$ to $n$.

The determinant of the system is of the Vandermonde form and its value is the product of all $x_i-x_j$, hence nonzero.

Hence we only have the trivial solution.

[image]

Comment: Notice the typo in the figure. The rows should start with index $0$.